# Configuration with Config needed for anonymous Users - Image is not Rendering with Sitecore

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I have integrated Sitecore with my application.
The whole application is rendering all content, but the images from the Media Library are not loaded.
After I have logged in with the Sitecore Applcation, the images are loading.
If I log out the images are not loaded.
Configuration with Config needed for anonymous Users?

Comment: Have you published images? Check their items in Media Library

Comment: Yes i have published. It is there in Media Library. It is not allowing anonymous users, that's the issue.

Comment: Go to sitecore desktop (`/sitecore/shell`), switch to `web` database and check if images are there. If no, it means that something was not published (images, their ancestors or something). Maybe they are in workflow. If they are in `web` database, check `Access Viewer` application if something blocks access to the images.

Comment: How to switch to web database

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is caused by security having been applied to the media library folder. Perhaps you were trying to ensure that only certain editors could add images to the folder, but in doing so have removed access to all other users such as the anonymous user.

Check with the Access Viewer what the extranet\Anonymous user can see in the Media Library folder where your images are stored.

Comment: <domain name="sitecore" ensureAnonymousUser="false" />
  <domain name="extranet" />
  <domain name="default" isDefault="true" />
  <!-- 
      Domain templates
      Use sc:templateName to name a specific template (and sc:template to reference it).
      Note that currently, default properties must be written as elements (rather than attributes).
    -->
  <sc:templates>
    <domain type="Sitecore.Security.Domains.Domain, Sitecore.Kernel">
      <ensureAnonymousUser>true</ensureAnonymousUser>
      <locallyManaged>false</locallyManaged>
    </domain>
  </sc:templates>

Comment: the above is the config which we used

Comment: In extranet\Anonymous is everything checked

Comment: But there is no sitecore/Anonymous